# How to get the difference between two dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, and I need to find the difference between the two, which should give me both a key and a value.

I have searched and found some addons/packages like datadiff and dictdiff-master, but when I try to import them in Python 2.7, it says that no such modules are defined.

I used a set here:

```py
first_dict = {}
second_dict = {}
 
value = set(second_dict) - set(first_dict)
print value
```

My output is:

```py
>>> set(['SCD-3547', 'SCD-3456'])
```

I am getting only keys, and I need to also get the values.

Comment: Would you also need to find a difference if the keys are identical but their values differ?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try the following snippet, using a dictionary comprehension:

```
value = { k : second_dict[k] for k in set(second_dict) - set(first_dict) }
```

In the above code we find the difference *of the keys* and then rebuild a `dict` taking the corresponding values.

Comment: Since both `dict` and `set` are hashmaps, I don't know why `dict` can't support a `difference()` method, given that `set` does.

Comment: That just gives you the dict for the keys which were in the second dict but not in the first. What about the things which were in the first but not in second?

Comment: @henryJack You can do something like the following to also compare values: `value = { k : second_dict[k] for k, _ in set(second_dict.items()) - set(first_dict.items()) }`

Doing `dict.items()` gives tuples from keys to values, and those are compared in the set difference. So this will give all new keys as well as changed values.

Comment: @ascrookes - Yes! I'll update my answer to reflect this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48544451/6782278

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: To be sure to see a difference that might be there you have to do it again while switching `second_dict` and `first_dict` making the result symmetric.

Comment: I think you don't need to convert the dict keys to sets, you can just use the set operations on the keys, like so: `second_dict.keys() - first_dict.keys()`

Comment: How about `{ k: v for k,v in dict1.items() if k not in dict2}` ?

Comment: I'm impressed how @henryJack used these comments to enhance his submitted answer to the OP's question. Nice 'circle back around'.

Comment: @Óscar López I have a question, what if it has the same keys but a different hash.

Comment: Set elements must be immutable. For example, a tuple may be included in a set:

`x = { 10 , ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'hello' , 2.71}`

But lists and dictionaries are mutable, so they can't be set elements,
so you get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' or TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: @MuneebAhmadKhurram The hash of a key is used for lookup, not for determining if a key is already present. There is always the possibility of a hash collision, as a hash function only guarantees that `hash(x) == hash(y)` if `x == y`; it says nothing about the relationship between `hash(x)` and `hash(y)` if `x != y`. When distinct keys have the same hash, it can slow down key access, but not break it.

Comment: This doesn't work for dictionaries with same keys but different values

Comment: @Ghasem lol, and it will never, ever work like that. Dictionaries _by their own definition_ map a single key to a unique value, there's no such thing as having "same keys with different values", you want a multimap for that.

Answer (score 220):

I think it's better to use the symmetric difference operation of sets to do that [Here is the link to the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference).

```
>>> dict1 = {1:'donkey', 2:'chicken', 3:'dog'}
>>> dict2 = {1:'donkey', 2:'chimpansee', 4:'chicken'}
>>> set1 = set(dict1.items())
>>> set2 = set(dict2.items())
>>> set1 ^ set2
{(2, 'chimpansee'), (4, 'chicken'), (2, 'chicken'), (3, 'dog')}
```

It is symmetric because:

```
>>> set2 ^ set1
{(2, 'chimpansee'), (4, 'chicken'), (2, 'chicken'), (3, 'dog')}
```

This is not the case when using the [difference operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference).

```
>>> set1 - set2
{(2, 'chicken'), (3, 'dog')}
>>> set2 - set1
{(2, 'chimpansee'), (4, 'chicken')}
```

However it may not be a good idea to convert the resulting set to a dictionary because you may lose information:

```
>>> dict(set1 ^ set2)
{2: 'chicken', 3: 'dog', 4: 'chicken'}
```

Comment: Excellent, this is more or less the same solution suggested by Raymond Hettinger nearly 9 years ago on another forum: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576644-diff-two-dictionaries/#c1

Comment: Elegant solution. But it cannot apply on the dicts with unhashable values.

Comment: I suspect this answer is what OP really needed and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Helps me to do the math in one line : dict(set(a.items()) ^ set(b.items()))

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: Nice. But you probably also want to know which dict was responsible for which key/value pair.

Comment: @LeiYang your dictionary maybe surrounded by "[]' which means it is list. So first make dictionary from list.

Comment: @LeiYang you get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` because one of the values inside your "top level dict" is another dict. **This proposed solution only works for *flat* dictionaries**

Comment: I am using dictionary inside dictionary and it is failing with error message : ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'```

Comment: Set elements must be immutable. For example, a tuple may be included in a set:

`x = { 10 , ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'hello' , 2.71}`

But lists and dictionaries are mutable, so they can't be set elements,
so you get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' or TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: None of the presented solutions which utilize `set(...)` will operate on unhashable types present in either dictionary keys or values.

Comment: it won't work if you have nested dictionaries

Answer (score 85):

Another solution would be `dictdiffer` (https://github.com/inveniosoftware/dictdiffer).

```
import dictdiffer                                          

a_dict = {                                                 
  'a': 'foo',
  'b': 'bar',
  'd': 'barfoo'
}                                                          

b_dict = {                                                 
  'a': 'foo',                                              
  'b': 'BAR',
  'c': 'foobar'
}                                                          

for diff in list(dictdiffer.diff(a_dict, b_dict)):         
    print(diff)
```

A diff is a tuple with the type of change, the changed value, and the path to the entry.

```
('change', 'b', ('bar', 'BAR'))
('add', '', [('c', 'foobar')])
('remove', '', [('d', 'barfoo')])
```

Comment: The most practical solution for debugging.

Comment: The other solutions did not solve my issue because of my dict-in-dict structure. This solution could handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

You can use [DeepDiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff):

```
pip install deepdiff
```

Among other things, it lets you recursively calculate the difference of dictionaries, iterables, strings and other objects:

```py
>>> from deepdiff import DeepDiff

>>> d1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, "foo":4}
>>> d2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3, "bar":5, 6:6}
>>> DeepDiff(d1, d2)
{'dictionary_item_added': [root['bar'], root[6]],
 'dictionary_item_removed': [root['foo']],
 'values_changed': {'root[2]': {'new_value': 4, 'old_value': 2}}}
```

It lets you see what changed (even types), what was added and what was removed. It also lets you do many other things like ignoring duplicates and ignoring paths (defined by regex).

Answer (score 18):

A solution is to use the `unittest` module:

```
from unittest import TestCase
TestCase().assertDictEqual(expected_dict, actual_dict)
```

Obtained from [How can you test that two dictionaries are equal with pytest in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201358/how-can-you-test-that-two-dictionaries-are-equal-with-pytest-in-python)

Comment: This is pretty cool but doesn't work in Python 2: `ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unittest.case.TestCase'>: runTest`

Comment: @Matt All my condolences if you're still using Python 2 !

Comment: Please drop python 2 dude - it's no more supported officially by python

Answer (score 12):

You were right to look at using a set, we just need to dig in a little deeper to get your method to work.

First, the example code:

```
test_1 = {"foo": "bar", "FOO": "BAR"}
test_2 = {"foo": "bar", "f00": "b@r"}
```

We can see right now that both dictionaries contain a similar key/value pair:

```
{"foo": "bar", ...}
```

Each dictionary also contains a completely different key value pair. But how do we detect the difference? Dictionaries don't support that. Instead, you'll want to use a set.

Here is how to turn each dictionary into a set we can use:

```
set_1 = set(test_1.items())
set_2 = set(test_2.items())
```

This returns a set containing a series of tuples. Each tuple represents one key/value pair from your dictionary.

Now, to find the difference between set_1 and set_2:

```
print set_1 - set_2
>>> {('FOO', 'BAR')}
```

Want a dictionary back? Easy, just:

```
dict(set_1 - set_2)
>>> {'FOO': 'BAR'}
```

Comment: Please note this is not symmetrical, you'll need to do `(set 2 - set 1)` in addition to `(set 1 - set 2)`. Else you will not capture all the differences, such as `{("f00": "b@r")}`, which is missing here in the output.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend using something already written by good developers. Like `pytest`. It has a deal with any data type, not only dicts. And, BTW, `pytest` is very good at testing.

```py
from _pytest.assertion.util import _compare_eq_any

print('\n'.join(_compare_eq_any({'a': 'b'}, {'aa': 'vv'}, verbose=3)))
```

Output is:

```
Left contains 1 more item:
{'a': 'b'}
Right contains 1 more item:
{'aa': 'vv'}
Full diff:
- {'aa': 'vv'}
?    -    ^^
+ {'a': 'b'}
?        ^
```

If you don't like using private functions (started with `_`), just have a look at the source code and copy/paste the function to your code.

P.S.: Tested with `pytest==6.2.4`

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Incredibly useful for environments where you have pytest but don't want to install a new package just to do a diff in a notebook!

Answer (score 10):

This is my own version, from combining https://stackoverflow.com/a/67263119/919692 with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48544451/919692, and now I see it is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47433207/919692:

```
def dict_diff(dict_a, dict_b, show_value_diff=True):
  result = {}
  result['added']   = {k: dict_b[k] for k in set(dict_b) - set(dict_a)}
  result['removed'] = {k: dict_a[k] for k in set(dict_a) - set(dict_b)}
  if show_value_diff:
    common_keys =  set(dict_a) & set(dict_b)
    result['value_diffs'] = {
      k:(dict_a[k], dict_b[k])
      for k in common_keys
      if dict_a[k] != dict_b[k]
    }
  return result
```

Comment: first_dict is not defined

Comment: Thanks for noticing, @Crystal, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

This function gives you all the diffs (and what stayed the same) based on the dictionary keys only. It also highlights some nice Dict comprehension, Set operations and python 3.6 type annotations :)

```
from typing import Dict, Any, Tuple
def get_dict_diffs(a: Dict[str, Any], b: Dict[str, Any]) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Any], Dict[str, Any], Dict[str, Any], Dict[str, Any]]:

    added_to_b_dict: Dict[str, Any] = {k: b[k] for k in set(b) - set(a)}
    removed_from_a_dict: Dict[str, Any] = {k: a[k] for k in set(a) - set(b)}
    common_dict_a: Dict[str, Any] = {k: a[k] for k in set(a) & set(b)}
    common_dict_b: Dict[str, Any] = {k: b[k] for k in set(a) & set(b)}
    return added_to_b_dict, removed_from_a_dict, common_dict_a, common_dict_b
```

If you want to compare the dictionary *values*:

```
values_in_b_not_a_dict = {k : b[k] for k, _ in set(b.items()) - set(a.items())}
```

Comment: Wouldn't common_dict_a and common_dict_b be the same? Whatever is common to A and B is one set of key:value pairs. No need to duplicate.

Comment: The keys are the same; but the values might be different. That is why that is there.

Answer (score 8):

A function using the symmetric difference set operator, as mentioned in other answers, which preserves the origins of the values:

```py
def diff_dicts(a, b, missing=KeyError):
    """
    Find keys and values which differ from `a` to `b` as a dict.

    If a value differs from `a` to `b` then the value in the returned dict will
    be: `(a_value, b_value)`. If either is missing then the token from 
    `missing` will be used instead.

    :param a: The from dict
    :param b: The to dict
    :param missing: A token used to indicate the dict did not include this key
    :return: A dict of keys to tuples with the matching value from a and b
    """
    return {
        key: (a.get(key, missing), b.get(key, missing))
        for key in dict(
            set(a.items()) ^ set(b.items())
        ).keys()
    }
```

### Example

```py
print(diff_dicts({'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'b': 2, 'c': 2}))

# {'c': (<class 'KeyError'>, 2), 'a': (1, <class 'KeyError'>), 'b': (1, 2)}
```

### How this works

We use the symmetric difference set operator on the tuples generated from taking items. This generates a set of distinct `(key, value)` tuples from the two dicts.

We then make a new dict from that to collapse the keys together and iterate over these. These are the only keys that have changed from one dict to the next.

We then compose a new dict using these keys with a tuple of the values from each dict substituting in our missing token when the key isn't present.

Comment: This works great! But it not working when one or both dicts contains lists: set(a.items()) ^ set(b.items())
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 8):

Not sure this is what the OP asked for, but this is what I was looking for when I came across this question - specifically, how to show key by key the difference between two dicts:

**Pitfall: when one dict has a missing key, and the second has it with a None value, the function would assume they are similar**

*This is not optimized at all - suitable for small dicts*

```
def diff_dicts(a, b, drop_similar=True):
    res = a.copy()

    for k in res:
        if k not in b:
            res[k] = (res[k], None)

    for k in b:
        if k in res:
            res[k] = (res[k], b[k])
        else:
            res[k] = (None, b[k])

    if drop_similar:
        res = {k:v for k,v in res.items() if v[0] != v[1]}

    return res


print(diff_dicts({'a': 1}, {}))
print(diff_dicts({'a': 1}, {'a': 2}))
print(diff_dicts({'a': 2}, {'a': 2}))
print(diff_dicts({'a': 2}, {'b': 2}))
print(diff_dicts({'a': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 1}))
```

Output:

```
{'a': (1, None)}
{'a': (1, 2)}
{}
{'a': (2, None), 'b': (None, 2)}
{'b': (None, 1)}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this? Not as pretty but explicit.

```
orig_dict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
new_dict = {'a' : 2, 'v' : 'hello', 'b' : 2}

updates = {}
for k2, v2 in new_dict.items():
    if k2 in orig_dict:    
        if v2 != orig_dict[k2]:
            updates.update({k2 : v2})
    else:
        updates.update({k2 : v2})

#test it
#value of 'a' was changed
#'v' is a completely new entry
assert all(k in updates for k in ['a', 'v'])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def flatten_it(d):
    if isinstance(d, list) or isinstance(d, tuple):
        return tuple([flatten_it(item) for item in d])
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        return tuple([(flatten_it(k), flatten_it(v)) for k, v in sorted(d.items())])
    else:
        return d

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1}

print set(flatten_it(dict1)) - set(flatten_it(dict2)) # set([('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
# or 
print set(flatten_it(dict2)) - set(flatten_it(dict1)) # set([('b', 1)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but thought I'd share my solution anyway. Pretty simple.

```
dicta_set = set(dicta.items()) # creates a set of tuples (k/v pairs)
dictb_set = set(dictb.items())
setdiff = dictb_set.difference(dicta_set) # any set method you want for comparisons
for k, v in setdiff: # unpack the tuples for processing
    print(f"k/v differences = {k}: {v}")
```

This code creates two sets of tuples representing the k/v pairs. It then uses a set method of your choosing to compare the tuples. Lastly, it unpacks the tuples (k/v pairs) for processing.

Answer (score 1):

This will return a new dict (only changed data).

```
def get_difference(obj_1: dict, obj_2: dict) -> dict:
result = {}

for key in obj_1.keys():
    value = obj_1[key]

    if isinstance(value, dict):
        difference = get_difference(value, obj_2.get(key, {}))

        if difference:
            result[key] = difference

    elif value != obj_2.get(key):
        result[key] = obj_2.get(key, None)

return result
```

Answer (score 1):

For one side comparison you can use dict comprehension:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
dict2 = {'a': OMG, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

data = {a:dict1[a] for a in dict1 if dict1[a] != dict2[a]}
```

output: {'a': 1}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation that lets you update dict1 values if you know the values in dict2 are right.

Consider:

```
dict1.update((k, dict2.get(k)) for k, v in dict1.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_dic={'a':1, 'b':2}
b_dic={'a':1, 'b':20}

sharedmLst = set(a_dic.items()).intersection(b_dic.items())
diff_from_b = set(a_dic.items()) - sharedmLst
diff_from_a = set(b_dic.items()) - sharedmLst

print("Among the items in a_dic, the item different from b_dic",diff_from_b)
print("Among the items in b_dic, the item different from a_dic",diff_from_a)
```

---

```
Result :
Among the items in a_dic, the item different from b_dic {('b', 2)}
Among the items in b_dic, the item different from a_dic {('b', 20)}
```

Comment: Please include some explanation into your answer besides code.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works perfectly with unhashable dicts, which fixes this error:

```
TypeError: Unhashable type 'dict'.
```

Start with the top-ranked solution from @Roedy. We create a dictionary of lists, which are a good example of something that is non-hashable:

```
>>> dict1 = {1:['donkey'], 2:['chicken'], 3:['dog']}
>>> dict2 = {1:['donkey'], 2:['chimpansee'], 4:['chicken']}
```

Then we preprocess to make each value hashable using `str(value)`:

```
>>> set1 = set([(key, str(value)) for key, value in dict1.items()])
>>> set2 = set([(key, str(value)) for key, value in dict2.items()])
```

Then we continue as per answer from @Reody:

```
>>> set1 ^ set2
{(3, "['dog']"), (4, "['chicken']"), (2, "['chimpansee']"), (2,"['chicken']")}
```

Comment: Note: The values are now display-only, as they have been converted to a string so they can be hashed. However, now we know the differences, we can refer back to the original dictionary.

Comment: Note: Efficiency wise, this is not all that fast as it converts all values to a string, it may be quicker to use the hash function on each value.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, the [datatest package](https://datatest.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will check for differences in dictionaries, numpy arrays, pandas dataframes, etc. Datatest also lets you also set a tolerance for floating point comparisons.

```
from datatest import validate, accepted
def test_compare_dict():
    expected = {"key1": 0.5}
    actual = {"key1": 0.499}
    with accepted.tolerance(0.1):
        validate(expected, actual)
```

Differences result in a `datatest.ValidationError` that contains the relevant Invalid, Deviation, Missing, or Extra items.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3 I'm getting `unhashable type: 'dict'` errors. I know OP asked for Python 2.7, but since it's already deprecated, here's Python 3 compatible function:

```
def dict_diff(a, b):
    diff = {}
    for k,v in a.items():
        if k not in b:
            diff[k] = v
        elif v != b[k]:
            diff[k] = '%s != %s' % (v, b[k])
    for k,v in b.items():
        if k not in a:
            diff[k] = v

    return diff
```

the output is following:

```
  d1 = {1:'donkey', 2:'chicken', 3:'dog'}
  d2 = {1:'donkey', 2:'chimpansee', 4:'chicken'}

  diff = dict_diff(d1, d2)
  # {2: 'chicken != chimpansee', 3: 'dog', 4: 'chicken'}
```