# How can you test that two dictionaries are equal with pytest in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Trying to assert that two dictionaries that have nested contents are equal to each other (order doesn't matter) with pytest. What's the pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `assert d1 == d2`? Btw what is your nested content?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Don't spend your time writing this logic yourself. Just use the functions provided by the default testing library `unittest`

```
from unittest import TestCase
TestCase().assertDictEqual(expected_dict, actual_dict)
```

Comment: When dict is big, and we no see diff details, variant use with params maxDiff:
test = TestCase() | test.maxDiff = None | test.assertEqual(expected_dict, actual_dict)

Answer (score 78):

pytest's magic is clever enough. By writing

```py
assert {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4} } } == {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4} } }
```

you will have a nested test on equality.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The desired functionality is already there automatically in pytest when you assert that two dictionaries are equal. There's no need either to write dedicated logic or to import anything from unittest.

Comment: It isn't even pytest. This is just using the regular Python equality operator. Only if the assertion fails does pytest's magic kick in to display the dicts and/or their differences.

Answer (score 9):

I guess a simple assert equality test should be okay:

```
>>> d1 = {n: chr(n+65) for n in range(10)}
>>> d2 = {n: chr(n+65) for n in range(10)}
>>> d1 == d2
True
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d2[10] = l2
>>> d1[10] = l1
>>> d1 == d2
True
>>> class Example:
    stub_prop = None
>>> e1 = Example()
>>> e2 = Example()
>>> e2.stub_prop = 10
>>> e1.stub_prop = 'a'
>>> d1[11] = e1
>>> d2[11] = e2
>>> d1 == d2
False
```

Answer (score 7):

General purpose way is to:

```
import json

# Make sure you sort any lists in the dictionary before dumping to a string

dictA_str = json.dumps(dictA, sort_keys=True)
dictB_str = json.dumps(dictB, sort_keys=True)

assert dictA_str == dictB_str
```

Comment: works, but it's very tedious to find the difference between the two objects afterwards

Answer (score 0):

```
assert all(v == actual_dict[k] for k,v expected_dict.items()) and len(expected_dict) == len(actual_dict)
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. If two dicts are equal then necessarily their lengths will be the same, and so will be their elements. Barely `dict1==dict2` does the trick. Also to be rigurous, if item per item check was neccesary, you would need to go over the nested elements too.

Comment: Said simple evaluation does exactly a multi-dimension-wise check, as opposed to the `is` operator, that solely checks for the memory pointer.

Answer (score -4):

your question is not very specific but with what i can understand, you are either trying to check if the length are the same

```
a = [1,5,3,6,3,2,4]
b = [5,3,2,1,3,5,3]

if (len(a) == len(b)):
    print True
else:
    print false
```

or checking if the list values are the same

```
import collections

compare = lambda x, y: collections.Counter(x) == collections.Counter(y)
compare([1,2,3], [1,2,3,3])
print compare #answer would be false
compare([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
print compare #answer would be true
```

but for dictionaries you could also use

```
x = dict(a=1, b=2)
y = dict(a=2, b=2)

if(x == y):
    print True
else:
    print False
```