# Is it possible to force a dataclass field to call its default_factory when the supplied argument is None?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass with a mutable field (a list). What I'm hoping to achieve is that this field will never be None, even when explicitly set to None in the __init__ call. In a normal class this would be trivial to implement:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, l: Optional[List[int]] = None):
        if l is None:
            l = []
        self.l = l
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result with just the [dataclasses.field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) function, i.e. without explicitly implementing an __init__ method (which would be cumbersome when the class has a lot of attributes)? Can I force dataclasses.field to call its `default_factory` when the supplied init argument is None?

Comment: Do you want the following behaviour: a = A(None) then a.l == [ ] ? Or a=A() then a.l == [ ]?

Comment: The former, the latter is what the `default_factory` is intended for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think, that it is possible to directly force the default_factory to be called on explicit provied None values. But you can use the `__post_init__` method to explicitly check for None and provide a default_value, in particular if you have to check many attributes.

You can use the `fields` function to scan your dataclass' automatically for `None` values and invoke default_factory for those attributes, if it was provided:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields, MISSING
from typing import List

@dataclass
class A:
    l: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        for f in fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, f.name)   
            if value is None and not f.default_factory is MISSING:
                setattr(self, f.name, f.default_factory())

s = A([1,2])
print(s.l)  # [1,2]

t = A(None)
print(t.l)  # []
```

Comment: Roughly so, but the factory should only be called when `self.__dict__[field.name] is None`. I would also be careful with using `MISSING` directly, the docs advise against this. One could simply do `if callable(field.default_factory)`.

Comment: I forgot checking for none in the first version. I updated my answer to check for None values.

Comment: I am not shure about MISSING. The docs also say that it is a sentinel value to indicate if a default_factory was provided. Since missing is encapsulated by the defined dataclass or Mixin, this might be ok to use in this case. callable(field.default_factory) relies on the fact, that callable(MISSING) == False but since field.default_factory is MISSING is true in case it default_factory was not provided, I am not shure if it is better than directly comparing against MISSING

Comment: @Hatatister I'd say that this case right here is actually a great use-case for `MISSING`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589794/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-dataclass-field-has-a-default-value

Comment: For what it's worth, the same can be achieved without checking for `MISSING` and just `try`ing settattr and excepting a `TypeError`, and is arguably more pythonic.

Comment: Using `try` `except TypeError` would also catch the unlikely case of raising a `TypeError` in `default_factory`.  I think of the case of raising a typeerror in `default_factory` which is caused by a bug in the code. In this case you would supress the bug and it would be very hard to detect. So checking explicit for MISSING could be the better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired result with `__post_init__` method which will set `self.l` to empty list even if it is `None`:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    l: Optional[List[int]]

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.l = self.l or []


a = A(None)
print(a.l)  # []
```

Comment: Yep, I've just had this idea myself and am currently trying to set up a mixin that does this automatically.

Comment: "Mixin that does this automatically" - sounds interesting.

Comment: Why, shouldn't I be able to simply inherit a \_\_post_init__ that does this for every class where it is needed?

Comment: Works just fine.

Comment: One disadvantage of this approach is static type checkers will see `l` as an Optional field that can sometimes be None.