# How to store diff of dict when inserting a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, diff

I need to efficiently have a diff dictionary that tells me what is the difference between a primary dictionary at some point at time, and now.

I need to have the full path to what is changed, not just the value that changed.

for example:

```
primary_dict = {'a': 5, 'b':{'c': 9}, 'd':10}
```

and the difference will be

```
diff_dict = {'a':6, 'b':{'c':8}}
```

to say that currently

```
primary_dict = {'a':6, 'b':{'c':8}, 'd':10}
```

I can have the diff created when values are added to the dict

I have looked online but only found comparisons between 2 dictionaries and that would inefficient because the dictionary I need to diff is massive and saving it 2 times and diffing it all recursively seems to much work for the problem at hand

EDIT:
Changed the question to be more on point.
like I have been notified the question that reflects my need is:
How do I get changes to a dictionary over time without creating a new variable?
Thank you to @CristiFati and @Vishnudev for the corrections

Comment: What if some new keys appear, or some are deleted?

Comment: @RoadRunner: "*I need to have the **full path** to what is changed, not just the value that changed.*".

Comment: @CristiFati Ah my bad, didn't read fully. Too tired.

Comment: @CristiFati sorry I didn't mention it, if keys appear I need to know about it.
If keys are deleted it doesn't matter all too much

Comment: @EdenK: What if they are removed? or what if they change type?

Comment: @CristiFati as far as changing types I guess it wouldn't change anything that doesn't depend on their types(a method that acts on the data).
when you remove items, is there a good way to represent it in the same data type(namely dictionary)?

Comment: @EdenK Could you re-phrase the exact question in a paragraph as I seem confused now due to changes and I think many people will be.

Comment: What I need is a way to have only 2 dictionaries.
for example the before_change dictionary and the diff dictionary.
I do not need the after change dictionary what so ever.
all I want to have is the diff between before_change when I started logging it and the current before_change.

I don't want to save before_change and compare it to after_change because it is very inefficient.
I hope it is more clear, thank you!

Comment: Basically you want to record all the changes that occurred in a dictionary in time. That's a totally different question.

Comment: @EdenK What you asked is not what you are explaining now. Why is there an after_change dict in the question if you don't need it? Please be clear with your question. The actual question should have been `How do I get changes to a dictionary over time without creating a new variable` right?

Comment: Please give at least a partial detailing of operations that can be applied to the original dictionary that you expect to track the resultant changes of.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dictdiffer` library

```
>>> from dictdiffer import diff
>>> before_change = {'a': 5, 'b':{'c': 9}, 'd':10}
>>> after_change = {'a': 6, 'b':{'c':8, 'd': 10}, 'd':10}
>>> list(diff(before_change, after_change))
[('change', 'a', (5, 6)), ('change', 'b.c', (9, 8)), ('add', 'b', [('d', 10)])]
```

For deleted keys,

```
>>> before_change = {'a': 5, 'b':{'c': 9}, 'd':10}
>>> after_change = {'a': 6, 'b':{'d': 10}, 'd':10}
>>> list(diff(before_change, after_change))
[('change', 'a', (5, 6)), ('add', 'b', [('d', 10)]), ('remove', 'b', [('c', 9)])]
```

Comment: Thank you,
I have two points in regard to your answer:
1. I need to have a primary dictionary that will hold all of the information and a second dictionary that just tells me what changed, not 2 whole primary dictionaries that are different a little(in my case they will differ in 1 element)
2. I need to be aware of the time complexity of the algorithm to determine if it is not too cpu consuming.

Comment: In the output dictionary you are expecting to get, you'll never know what got added and what got deleted @EdenK

Answer (score 0):

Probably OOPS may have a solution.

The dictionary may be only edited by a public function with a provision to create a log of what has changed.

Comment: I am sorry but what is OOPS?

Comment: @EdenK It's Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: @Vishnudev thank you, I thought it might be some book

Comment: Based on your latest comments Eden, it seems that that OOPs is actually suited. 
Check for "Data Encapsulation". This might help [link](https://pythonspot.com/encapsulation/)

Answer (score 0):

Complex solution (based on `set` operations and *recursive* function) for extended, complex input dictionaries:

As the title said the condition of interest is *"when inserting a value"*.

```
# extended input samples
before_change = {'a': 5, 'b': {'c': 9}, 'd': 10, 'g': {'h': {'k': 100}}}
after_change = {'a': 6, 'b': {'c': 9, 'f': 1}, 'd': 10, 'g': {'h': {'k': 300}}, 'e': 11}


def dict_diff(before, after):
    """Compute difference between dictionaries.
       Fetchs path to the innermost changed item"""

    new_keys = set(before) ^ set(after)
    diff = {k: after[k] for k in new_keys} # detecting new keys/items beforehand

    for k in set(before) & set(after):  # process intersected keys
        if before[k] != after[k]:
            if type(before[k]) is dict and type(after[k]) is dict:
                inner_diff = dict_diff(before[k], after[k])
                if inner_diff: diff[k] = inner_diff
            else:
                diff[k] = after[k]
    return diff

print(dict_diff(before_change, after_change))
```

The output:

```
{'e': 11, 'b': {'f': 1}, 'g': {'h': {'k': 300}}, 'a': 6}
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't what I need, 
I need to specifically NOT have to dictionaries to diff.
I need the primary dictionary with all of the information and the diff dictionary that just tells me what changed since I started to keep track.

Comment: @EdenK, what you posted in your question as desired result is `{'a':6, 'b':{'c':8}}`. It's obliviously comprehensible as the difference between dictionaries

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have now edited my question to make it clear what I need

Answer (score 0):

A similar question already exists: [[SO]: How to get the difference between two dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815640/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dictionaries-in-python). 
You could use a recursive approach.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def dummy_dict_diff(initial, final):
    ret = dict()
    for final_key, final_val in final.items():
        if final_key not in initial:  # Handle new keys
            ret[final_key] = final_val
            continue
        initial_val = initial[final_key]
        if final_val != initial_val:
            if type(final_val) != type(initial_val):
                ret[final_key] = final_val
            elif isinstance(final_val, (dict,)):
                ret[final_key] = dummy_dict_diff(initial_val, final_val)
            elif isinstance(final_val, (list, tuple)):
                ret[final_key] = final_val  # This would also require sequence diffs
            else:
                ret[final_key] = final_val
    deleted_keys = [item for item in initial if item not in final]  # Deleted keys
    for deleted_key in deleted_keys:
        ret[deleted_key] = initial[deleted_key]
    return ret


def main():
    before = {
        "a": 5,
        "b": {
            "c": 9
        },
        "d": 10
    }

    after = {
        "a": 6,
        "b": {
            "c": 8
        },
        "d": 10
    }

    print("Difference: {:}".format(dummy_dict_diff(before, after)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- There are some cases that are currently not handled. Handling them would require more code (and as an effect will also work slower):

  1. Sequence (e.g. *list*, *tuple*) values. Now, it's the final value (default case)

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056617962]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Difference: {'a': 6, 'b': {'c': 8}}
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict of comprehension:

```
actual_dict = {'a': 5, 'b':{'c': 9}, 'd':10}
diff_dict = {'a':6, 'b':{'c':8}}

primary_dict = {x: actual_dict[x] if x not in diff_dict.keys() else diff_dict[x] for x in actual_dict.keys()}

print(primary_dict)
```

**Output:**

> {'a': 6, 'b': {'c': 8}, 'd': 10}

Comment: Please read the comments, eden doesn't want to use the after_change dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following python code for getting the difference between two dictionaries:

```
before_change = {'a': 5, 'b':{'c': 9}, 'd':10}
after_change = {'a': 6, 'b':{'c':8}, 'd':10}

bc_values = list(before_change.values())
ac_values = list(after_change.values())
ac_keys = list(after_change.keys())

for item in range(len(bc_values)):
 if ac_values[item] == bc_values[item] :
   after_change.pop(ac_keys[item])

print(after_change)
```

The output of this code is:

```
{'a': 6, 'b': {'c': 8}}
```