# Create a list of new urls contained in objects in python

Tags: python

I have two json databases. If there is a new value in the "img_url" (one in the last json that isn't in the other), I want to print the url or place it in a variable. The goal is just to find a list of the new values.
Input json:

```
last_data = [
{
    "objectID": 16240,
    "results": [
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/30.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "objectID": 16242,
    "results": [
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/3.jpg"
        }
    ]
}]
# ...
#multiple other objectIDs
```

]

Second input:

```
second_data =[
{
    "objectID": 16240,
    "results": [
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/2.jpg"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "objectID": 16242,
    "results": [
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "img_url": "https://img.com/2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}...
#multiple other objectIDs
```

]

And I want to output only the `https://img.com/3.jpg` and the `https://img.com/3.jpg` urls (it can be a list because I have multiples objects) or place it in a variable

My code:

```
#last file
    for item_last in last_data:
        results_last = item_last["results"]
        if results_last is not []:
            for result_last in results_last:
                ccv_last = result_last["img_url"]
    #second file
    for item_second in second_data:
        results_second = item_second["results"]
        if results_second is not []:
        # loop in results
            for result_second in results_second:
                ccv_second = result_second["img_url"]

    if gm_last != gm_second and gm_last is not None:
    print(gm_last)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find difference between two different list here it is.
I have slightly modified your same code to get the expected result.

```
#last file
ccv_last = []
for item_last in last_data:
    results_last = item_last["results"]
    if results_last:
        for result_last in results_last:
            ccv_last.append(result_last["img_url"])
#second file
ccv_second = []
for item_second in second_data:
    results_second = item_second["results"]
    if results_second:
        for result_second in results_second:
            ccv_second.append(result_second["img_url"])

diff_list = list(set(ccv_last)-set(ccv_second)))
```

Output:

```
['https://img.com/30.jpg', 'https://img.com/3.jpg']
```

However you can plan to slightly change your results model for better performance please find below.

#### If you think no further keys are planned for the dictionaries in result list then probably you just want list. So you can change dict -> list

from

```
...
"results": [
    {
        "img_url": "https://img.com/1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "img_url": "https://img.com/2.jpg"
    }
]
...
```

to just list of urls

```
...
"img_url_results": ["https://img.com/1.jpg","https://img.com/2.jpg"]
...
```

By doing this change you can just skip one for loop.

```
#last file
ccv_last = []
for item_last in last_data:
    if item_last.get('img_url_results'):
       ccv_last.extend(item_last["img_url_results"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is that I have duplicates and I want to keep it and it's impossible with set()... How can I change that ?

Comment: You can use dictionary instead of list, please have a look at this solution it might help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41808831/9592801