# Python dictionaries shown as unequal despite no found differences

Tags: python

I'm comparing 2 dictionaries in Python, `loadedAgreement` and `latestDBAgreement`. I know from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4527957/1005607) that a **simple == or !=** can be used for dictionary comparison.

My dictionaries  come out as unequal, and to get the diffs, I used the approach [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815681/1005607):

```
value = { k : second_dict[k] for k in set(second_dict) - set(first_dict) }
```

from **both sides**. But when I do this from both sides, both results are empty `{}`. So why are the dictionaries still unequal?

```
diffvalues1 = { k : latestDBAgreement[k] for k in set(latestDBAgreement) - set(loadedAgreement) }
diffvalues2 = { k : loadedAgreement[k] for k in set(loadedAgreement) - set(latestDBAgreement) }
```

As you can see in the debugger, the code dropped into the `!=` section, but both diffs are empty.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815640/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dictionaries-in-python/32815681#comment84083883_32815681 - use the symmetric difference answer instead.

Comment: I did it from *both sides* . I did see that comment, so I'm aware of it: it's in the code. Did you see the phrase "both sides" ?

Comment: Your diff code is only comparing the *keys* of the two dicts.  It won't show if the same key has different values in each one.

Comment: So how do I get the different values as well?

Comment: You can use `set(d1.items()) - set(d2.items())`

Comment: And does this need to be done from both sides as well?

Comment: Yes, you should do it both ways.

Comment: If you use the top-voted answer (rather than just the _accepted_ one) on the linked post, it does both keys and values from both sides, unless there are issues with hashing.

Comment: Thanks. Does `set(d1.items()) ^ set(d2.items())` also include the key differences? For completeness, it needs to be both values and keys. That should be part of that answer too.

Comment: In Python dictionaries, items are (key, value) pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Dicts can also differ in **values**. To see which, you can do something like this:

```
{
    k: (v, latestDBAgreement[k])
    for k, v in loadedAgreement.items()
    if v != latestDBAgreement[k]}
```

(This of course assumes that the keys are the same, so it doesn't generalize.)