# Is there any standard python functions for comparing two dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, compare

I Have two dictionary and i want to compare them to understand which item added or deleted or modified it's value.

I write a class for doing compare two dict.

```
class CompareTwoDict:
    def __init__(self, dict1, dict2) -> None:
        self._dict1 = dict1
        self._dict2 = dict2
    
    def added_from_dict1(self):
        ...
    def deleted_from_dict1(self):
        ...
    def modified_from_dict1(self):
        ...
    def common_between_dict1_dict2(self):
        ...
```

**added_from_dict1** means any item in dict2 that is not in dict1.

**deleted_from_dict1** means any item in dict1 but it is not in dict2.

**modified_from_dict1** means item's value change in dict2.

**common_between_dict1_dict2** means items in dict1 and dict2 have the same key and value.

Is There any python standard function do it?

Comment: If your dict's values are [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) then you can implement it easily by converting dict into tuples and using `set` [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41808831/10909029)

Comment: Here's [demo code](https://gist.github.com/jupiterbjy/6d84bbe80b5279ed0695fc67ee176305) based on my understanding of what you're trying to achieve, feel free to check out if you find yourself lost.