# How to find keys in second dictionary which has different value compare to first dictionary

Tags: python

I can use `diff = set(dict2) - set(dict1)` to know that the `dict1` and `dict2` are not equal but what I need is to find which KEY in `dict2` has a different value than  `dict1`

```
 dict1 = {'c1': 'Iran', 'c2': 'India', 'c3': 'Iraq', 'c4': 'Qatar'}
 dict2 = {'c1': 'Iran', 'c2': 'India', 'c3': 'Iraqs','c4': 'Qeter'}
 diff = set(dict2) - set(dict1)
 print(diff)
```

Basically what I want to get in return are `{'c3', 'c4'}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815640/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
keys = set()
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2 and dict1[key] != dict2[key]:
        keys.add(key)

print(keys)
```

output:

```
{'c3', 'c4'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below:

```
dict1 = {'c1': 'Iran', 'c2': 'India', 'c3': 'Iraq', 'c4': 'Qatar'}
dict2 = {'c1': 'Iran', 'c2': 'India', 'c3': 'Iraqs', 'c4': 'Qeter'}
diff = set(dict2.items())-set(dict1.items())
diff_dict = dict(diff)
print(diff_dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to check same key in different dict.

```py
dict1 = {'c1': 'Iran', 'c2': 'India', 'c3': 'Iraq', 'c4': 'Qatar'}
dict2 = {'c1': 'Iran', 'c2': 'India', 'c3': 'Iraqs', 'c4': 'Qeter'}
diff = {k for k in dict2 if dict2[k] != dict1[k]}
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
{'c4', 'c3'}
```