# find common vales between the the same keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have changed dic 1 to dic 2 to find the common vales between the the same keys.  it is cleaned and I removed one number at the end in dic 1.
I wrote the function as follows to find the common features that is called common.

My final output should looks like as follows keeping the original format of common values, but I dont know how to implement it:

```
from functools import reduce

dic1 = {"df1":["age_0" , "nnn220","abc70"], "df2":["age_1" "a221","abc71"]} 

dic2 = {"df1":["age","nnn22","abc7"], "df2":["age", "a22","abc7"]} 

dataframe_list = list(dic2.values())
common = reduce(lambda a, b: set(a) & set(b), dataframe_list)



common = {'AGE',
 'abc7'}
```

```
final_output :{"df1":["age0", "abc70"], "df2":["age1","abc71"]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815640/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this is not a question. What do you need help with exactly? Why should that output come from that input? Like, what's the algorithm? For more tips, please read [ask]. You might also want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341)

Comment: No it doesn't !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use reduce to get your common values, just use `set.intersection`:

```
common = set.intersection(*map(set, dic2.values()))
```

As for filtering `dic1` you can use `re` and a comprehenesion like this:

```
is_common = re.compile("|".join(common)).match
result = {k: [e for e in v if is_common(e)] for k, v in dic1.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'df1': ['age_0', 'abc70'], 'df2': ['age_1a221', 'abc71']}
```

Comment: FYI, looks like you're missing a comma in dic1 between `age_1` and `a221` that's why the second list looks the way it does.

Comment: Thanks, what does "|"  is doing here ? why we can not use ","

Comment: And also what does * is doing

Comment: @ella The `*` unpacks the values from `map` so the sets are supplied instead of the `map` of sets. And the `|` is the delimiter because it means `or` in regex.